# How to increase speed of scroller

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit, cocos2d-x-3.0, bounce

I am developing a game in which a ball continuously bounces and falls on particular pole as shown in this gif: https://www.dropbox.com/s/43vwlbjoazaxe7u/jumpyBall_15_jul_15.gif?dl=0

Currently, I have put static values for how much high jump should be, distance between poles, time duration in which jump should be finished.

Now, if I need to speed up my game then height, duration, distance, etc. will needs to be reduced. Can anyone let me know how can I achieve my goal? Let me know if any formula can be of my help.

Comment: so is this about cocos2d, sprite kit, cocos2d-x , or is it really about game design ? voting to close, try on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: com'on guys. I used to log questions on gamedev.stack.... but it seems no one is answering me on that site. Don't know why I am unable to get proper answer and here you are trying to close my question as irrelevant topic :(

Comment: I have used formulas to calculate velocity so speed increase will not be major problem now. :)